# Quantum pressure and chemical potential for a Schwarzschild black hole?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, hawking-radiation, qft-in-curved-spacetime, chemical-potential

Just as Hawking showed that even Schwarzschild black holes have a temperature, shouldn't they also have a pressure and chemical potential? Are there any analytical formulae of those as well as
$$ T_{BH}=\dfrac{\hbar c^3}{8\pi GMk_B}$$?

I guess for the pressure (energy density) of Schwarzschild black holes this quantity:

$$P_S=\dfrac{E_S}{V_S}=\dfrac{k_BT_{BH}}{\dfrac{4\pi}{3}\left(\dfrac{2GM}{c^2}\right)^3}=\dfrac{3\hbar c^9}{256\pi^2G^4M_\odot^4}\left(\dfrac{M_\odot}{M}\right)^4 \approx 8\cdot 10^{-42}\left(\dfrac{M_\odot}{M}\right)^4\;\; Pa$$

However I am not sure if it is meaningful and how to guess the chemical potential (if any) for (quantum) Schwarzschild black holes... Has it any sense or not?

Comment: I'm not sure about the chemical potential, but there is some notion of pressure associated with Hawking radiation. It was [used by Unruh and Wald](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.25.942) to consider how the Generalized Second Law is not broken in a particular gendankenexperiment. It is also discussed in Wald's book, on the section concerning the Generalized Second Law. I don't recall whether they write a closed expression for the pressure, but I do recall that the important point was the existence of a pressure *gradient* as measured by observers outside the black hole

Comment: chemical potential is associated to charged objects and since the Schwarzschild BH is uncharged it has $\mu=0$.

Comment: @Prahar I know that, but consider the following argument: the Hawking radiation implies that black holes do emit particles, so they, in fact, have certain amount of (quantum) charge fluctuations! Therefore, even Schwarzschild should have a non-null chemical potential (of course it means that BH should have a quantum particle-antiparticle atmosphere, what in fact was one of the last contributions of Hawking himself...).

Comment: @riemannium - chemical potential, etc. are thermodynamic/statistical quantities that describe the average over some ensemble of systems. A black hole emitting Hawking radiation says nothing about its average behavior which is what classifies its temperature, chemical potential, etc.

Comment: @riemannium Also quantum fluctuations $\neq$ charge fluctuations.

Comment: One thing to note is, $E=kT$ is not a good equation for black holes, because larger mass/energy black holes have lower temperature.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in spacetime dynamics, and specifically for a black hole, there is a corresponding pressure, energy density, entropy, and even free energy of which can be calculated. A quick introduction (without the details such as those from Hawking's original paper ["4 Laws of Black Hole Thermodynamics"](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/communications-in-mathematical-physics/volume-31/issue-2/The-four-laws-of-black-hole-mechanics/cmp/1103858973.full)) is in Natsuume's 'user guide' on AdS/CFT, chapter 3:["AdS/CFT Dualiy Guide"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.3575).

So, using that reference, you can calculate the energy using the usual rules equations of thermodynamics, such as (eq. 3.33) $E = F + TS = \frac{r_0}{2G} = M$. Now, for chemical potential, think first about the original/classical meaning of $\mu$: how the different types (or species) of particles are emitted or absorbed with respect to the change in particle number. Now, recall how the Schwarzschild solution comes about: we are in a vacuum (no stress-energy tensor)! So our $\mu = 0$. But, for a charged black hole, the chemical potential is derived as (eq. 3.59, Natsuume), $$ \mu = A_0|_{r = \infty} - A_0|_{r=r_+} = \frac{Q}{r_+} = \sqrt{\frac{r_-}{Gr_+}}.$$

As a final note, these relationships are true regardless of AdS/CFT, so ignore that part of the guide unless you want to dive into it. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

A recent [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2108.06824) identifies the pressure of Schwarzschild black holes with the quantum corrections due to nonlocal terms in the effective quantum gravity action. In particular for a black hole of mass $M$ they find

$$P = − \gamma \frac{1}{2 G^4_N M^4}$$

where $\gamma$ is a positive constant for fields of spin 0, 1/2 and 2, and negative for spin 1.

Answer (score 0):

Black holes have pressure due to anomalous behavior of gravity under the influence of quantum - gravitational effect. This pressure is mathematically equal to $$P = \frac{hc^9}{G^4m^4}$$ its detail can be found in Ref[1](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4288217)

[1]https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4288217

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/402072)

Comment: Hi. The DOI and reference you write is not clear to me and the DOI gives me error...@Kapil

Comment: hello, I correct the link by adding other authentic link please find the link. [link] (https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=4288217) @riemannium.